# jQuery backstretch slideshow not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

I'm trying to get jquery backstretch going in a slideshow.  The code I have for the page so far is copied straight from the backstretch demo page: http://srobbin.com/demos/jquery-backstretch/examples/slideshow.html

The remit is for the page to be extremely simple and my code so far looks like this:

```
<head>
<title>Coconut Hotel Ecuador</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <script src="plugins/srobbin-jquery-backstretch-14ce02f/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/srobbin-jquery-backstretch-14ce02f/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                    $.backstretch(["beach.jpg", 
                    "swing.jpg"]);
                </script>
```

I've tried it with and without the duration and fade but no joy.  In addition, just using the one image, it works fine.  More than one it's just a white background.  Looking at firebug I get this error:

`<img style="position: absolute; display: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: medium none; z-index: -999999;" src="beach.jpg,swing.jpg">`

with the image source obviously not being found.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The only reason I can think (if it is not a bug) is that you have the paths (to the plugin or to the images) wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and was able to fix it by downloading the latest version of the plugin file (2.0.4). 
[You can get it at Github.](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch)